# Getting stackoverflow exception with Parallel for each , is this due to thread saftey?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a foreach loop which works Well . But I want to implement TPL , so did the following:

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileList, currentfileItem =>
{
    _clientContext.Load(currentfileItem, w => w.File);
    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (currentfileItem.File == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            String.Format("File information not found for the item {0}",
                currentfileItem.DisplayName));
    }

    var currentFileName = currentfileItem.File.Name;



    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRevVersionId))
    {
        var info = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(
            _clientContext, currentfileItem["fRef"].ToString());
        if (info != null)
        {
            UpdateToServer(Id, currentFileName, info.Stream);
        }
    }


});
```

Once I implement TPL I am getting `StackOverflow Exception` . I am pretty sure this is because of TPL because without TPL the application runs fine.

`fileList` is `IEnumerable<ListItem>`

**Edit:**

The SOE probably for this: (VS has ran out of memory to store the exception)
[image]

and updated code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileList,
                  () => CreateClientContext(ConfigurationDetails.SharePointUri), //This function creates a new context for the specified url. 
                  (currentfileItem, loopState, localContext) =>
                  {


                    _clientContext.Load(currentfileItem, w => w.File);
                    _clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    if (currentfileItem.File == null)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(String.Format("File information not found for the item {0}", currentfileItem.DisplayName));
                    }

                    var currentFileName = currentfileItem.File.Name;



                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRevVersionId))
                    {
                        var info = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(_clientContext, currentfileItem["fRef"].ToString());
                        if (info != null)
                        {
                            UpdateToServer(Id, currentFileName, info.Stream);
                        }
                    }


                },localContext => localContext.Dispose());

 private static ClientContext CreateClientContext(string URI)
        {
            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(URI);

            //...Magic...

            return context;
        }
```

Comment: What is the stack trace of the SOE?

Comment: What type is `_clientContext`? Is the methods `Load` and `ExecuteQuery` thread safe? It may not be a hard problem to solve but we need to see it's declration to show you how to fix it (you will need thread local instances of `_clientContext`)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain [ClientContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks Servy, from the MSDN page: "*Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.*" that's your problem. Show your declration of _clientContext and we can show you how to make thread local variables using `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah, but I wouldn't expect it to result in an SOE, but you're right, it probably shouldn't be shared across several threads.

Comment: It's screwing with internal state, if you changed a internal reference halfway though the `Load` or `ExecuteQuery` I would say it is not that too far out for it to happen.

Comment: @Servy, Stack Trae shows External code  but Exception Window Shows "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll" and what is SOE?

Comment: @Simsons Follow the trace back until it gets to your code.  Knowing that there's an SOE doesn't help much, knowing where it's coming from is rather essential.  Also being able to tell what external code is being called would help quite a lot; for example if you can confirm that it's the client context that's breaking, that would help.

Comment: We don't really care where the SOE itself happened, the important part is the last usercall code that happened before the SOE started. Click "[Copy exception details to the clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png)" then post the full exception details [as a edit to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19981744/edit) (be sure to highlight the text and press the `{ }` icon on the edit page to make sure the formatting does not get messed up).

Comment: SOE is happening with _clientContext.load , putting break point in all the lines helped and load and ExecuteQuery are sharepoint methods :(

Comment: @Simsons Yes, but the client context isn't built to be used from multiple threads at the same time.  You'll need to ensure that that doesn't happen, if that is indeed where the code is failing.

Comment: Thank you for asking this! I was struggling with multithreading for SP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ClientContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext%28v=office.14%29.aspx) is not thread safe, so you need to have one instance of it per thread. `Parallel.ForEach` has built in methods for making thread local objects, so you don't need to create it every loop iteration, just every thread spawning.

```
Parallel.ForEach(fileList, 
                 () => CreateClientContext(storeUrl), //This function creates a new context for the specified url. 
                 (currentfileItem, loopState, localContext) =>
{
    localContext.Load(currentfileItem, w => w.File);
    localContext.ExecuteQuery();

    if (currentfileItem.File == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(
            String.Format("File information not found for the item {0}",
                currentfileItem.DisplayName));
    }

    var currentFileName = currentfileItem.File.Name;



    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(docRevVersionId))
    {
        var info = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(
            localContext, currentfileItem["fRef"].ToString());
        if (info != null)
        {
            UpdateToServer(Id, currentFileName, info.Stream);
        }
    }

    return localContext;
},
              (localContext) => localContext.Dispose()); //Dispose the thread local context


//Elsewhere
private static ClientContext CreateClientContext(string url)
{
    ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);

    //Perform any additional setup you need on the context here.
    //If you don't need any you could just replace "CreateClientContext(storeUrl)"
    //with "new ClientContext(storeUrl)" up at the ForEach declaration.

    return context;
}
```

You may want to look in to `UpdateToServer` and check that it also is thread safe.

Comment: Note that this will likely require further refactoring as this would be using an item generated by a different context; I don't think that will work.

Comment: True, most likely the bulk of that refactored code would go in to the `//...Magic...` section so the context is set up pointing at the correct repository on the server.

Comment: Nah, just have the method accept a `string url` (the url can be closed over when calling the method) to be passed in and then new one up using that url.  That's all it'll take for that method.

Comment: Updated with parallel option ( Creating new ClientContext ) but still getting SOE

Comment: Well post the full stack trace as a edit to your question (Click the Copy Exception Details link I mentioned in a comment), also include a copy of your new version of your code to show the changes you made (and we can see if you made any mistakes).

Comment: @Simsons You never replaced `_clientContext` with `localContext` inside the loop. you need to replace the calls at `_clientContext.Load`, `_clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` and `OpenBinaryDirect(_clientContext, ...` with `localContext.Load`, `localContext.ExecuteQuery()` and `OpenBinaryDirect(localContext, ...`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Did that  and SOE Gone, But Now  currentFileName = currentfileItem.File.Name; pops up with exception that File.Name 'threw an not initialized exception' . Still trying to find out whether it's due to fileList (IEnumerable<ListItem>) or Sharepoint Client Context that's unable to initizalize the currentfileItem.File with actual value ...

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer!