# StackOverflow Exception in Sharepoint online

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am trying to add new column value in share-point online using multiple threads. But I am get a stackoverflow exception. Can you please help me. This is my code:

```
try
{
    foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in listCol)
    {
        if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
        {
            if (!item["FileLeafRef"].ToString().Contains(".tmd"))
            {

                item[propertyName] = propertyValue;  // this line is cause of error
                item.Update();                       // this line is cause of error                     
            }
        }
    }
    ExecuteQueryWithRetry(clientContext);
}
catch (StackOverflowException ex)
{
    Logger.LogException(ex, "Adding Values", "CMM " + "Adding Values");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code snippet below to update file items' Title property in my side, it's working as expected:

```
            using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/"))
            {

                ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(account, secret);
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                ListItemCollection ItemCol = targetList.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
                ctx.Load(ItemCol);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in ItemCol)
                {
                    if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
                    {
                        if (!item["FileLeafRef"].ToString().Contains(".tmd"))
                        {

                            item["Title"] = "TestTitle";  
                            item.Update();                       

                        }
                    }
                    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                }
             }
```

Comment: yes , its work fine for single thread but its not work in case of multi threads . for example I have 50 items in listItem collection and assign 25 items to each thread to process then in this case it will face stackover flow exception , The problem is ClientContext  is not thread save!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981744/getting-stackoverflow-exception-with-parallel-for-each-is-this-due-to-thread-s

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information, I checked about the ClientContext document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/ee538685(v%3Doffice.15) Actually instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.